# How to rotate login screen in gdm3

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, gdm, display-rotation

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, wayland and gnome in a 3 monitors configuration. And the monitor in the middle is rotated to vertical orientation. When I log in all works well, but the login screen is rotated to the left.

How do I configure the login screen to use the monitor in the middle in vertical position

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a while I used a combination of solutions, between lightdm and and older gdm.

First, you must log for the first time and configure every monitor in the way you want.

Then, copy the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config` folder.

Log out and gdm should be using your configuration

Comment: this did not work for me unfortunately